# memcpy doubts. Needs clarifications

Tags: c, memcpy

I got a memcpy function that look strange on how it was used. I pasted it below. Can someone please help explain it. I do not know why the (void *). buffer is buffer in struct BLK. Thanks.

```
    memcpy(     
                (void *) (BLK->buffer + left),
                (void *) input,
                fill            
          );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the cast, assuming `input` and `BLK->buffer` are already pointer types (which they really should be).

I can think of two reasons why they're there:

- The author was paranoid.
- The author was making it clear that he/she understands that the specific pointer type is going into a "generic" function.

Comment: and if they aren't pointers then you're almost definitely doing something wrong. in this case the cast will hide the problem.

Comment: Extra bullet: The author was confused by C++, Microsoft, and/or Herb Schildt.

Comment: Or the author was so oblivious that he didn't realize he compiled his C code on a C++ compiler.

Comment: Even C++ has implicit conversions *to* void pointers. It's the other direction that C++ nonsensically lacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

may be the author wanted to be very sure that the compiler will not make errors doing its job :-)

In C, casting a object pointer from and to a void * is not needed.
A pointer to a function is another thing.